# "He was too busy to work at a factory" - Is this sentence correct in grammar?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I know this sentence is correct.
He was too busy **working** at a factory.

but I wonder whether this sentence is correct and natural. (specially in grammar)

He was too busy **to work** at a factory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatical, but mean different things.

> He was too busy working at a factory.

means that because he was working at a factory so much, he could not do anything else.

> He was too busy to work at a factory.

means that because he was doing something else so much, he could not work at a factory.

Comment: To expand, one might say "He was too busy working at the factory to notice that his wife was cheating on him every afternoon".  So with that sentence, he **is** working at the factory, and that work is precluding him from doing other stuff.  The other phrase would be used "Between caring for his toddler, writing a novel, and doing stand-up comedy, he was too busy to work at the factory".  So in that case, he's **not** working at the factory, because other things are precluding him from doing that.

Answer (score 6):

> Busy + v. + ing
>
> He was too busy working at a factory.

= He was occupied with working at a factory.  *(he was actually working at a factory)*

---

> Too + adj. + to + v.(inf.)
>
> He was too busy to work at a factory.

= He was occupied with doing something else *(not working at a factory)* that prevented him from working at a factory.

Comment: To enlarge upon mohamed's correct answer, consider these variations: too thirsty to speak; too heavy to fight in the welterweight division; too short to be a professional basketball player; too weak to be a weightlifter; too preoccupied with texting on his mobile phone to see the trash truck coming down the street; too sore from running the marathon to climb the stairs up to his third-floor apartment.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if I point out that 'The colourless green squares rolled speedily up the perpendicular mountain' is wholly correct, it will show how careful you have to be about thinking that a grammatically correct sentence will produce a meaningful statement.

Comment: That is an interesting illustration,  but it doesn't really answer the question.